# Let $f(x):=(\sin(x)/x)^2$ and $g(x):=e^{i2x}f(x)$. Show that $f*g=0$

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

This is an exercise of the book *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher:

> Let $f(x):=(\sin(x)/x)^2$ and $g(x):=e^{i2x}f(x)$. Show that $f*g=0$.

Before to begin my definition of the Fourier transform:

$$
\hat h(\xi):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx,\quad\text{for }h\in L_1(\Bbb R)\tag1
$$

Now some facts to use here, for $f$ and $g$ of the exercise we have
$$
\hat f(\xi)=\sqrt{\frac\pi 8}(2-|\xi|)\chi_{[-2,2]}(\xi),\quad\hat g(\xi)=\hat f(\xi-2)\tag2
$$

Also I know that
$$
\widehat{h*\ell}=\sqrt{2\pi}\hat h\hat\ell,\quad\text{for }h,\ell\in L_1(\Bbb R)\tag3
$$
And also I know that the Fourier transform, restricted to $L_1$, is linear and injective (with dense image in $C_0$). Then $f*g=0\iff \widehat{f*g}=0$ a.e., and from all the above we have that
$$
\begin{align}\hat f\hat g(\xi)&=\frac8\pi(2-|\xi|)(2-|\xi-2|)\chi_{[-2,2]}(\xi)\chi_{[-2,2]}(\xi-2)\\
&=\frac8\pi(2-|\xi|)(2-|\xi-2|)\chi_{[-2,2]\cap[0,4]}(\xi)\\
&=\frac8\pi(2-|\xi|)(2-|\xi-2|)\chi_{[0,2]}(\xi)\\
&=\frac8\pi(2-\xi)\xi\chi_{[0,2]}(\xi)
\end{align}
$$

However $\hat f\hat g\neq 0$ a.e. and Im 100% sure that $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are absolutely correct (I checked them many times, using also Wolfram Mathematica to see if I had some silly mistake).

So, what is wrong? It is possible that the exercise is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is wrong. According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(sin(tau)%5E4*exp(-(2*I)*tau)%2Ftau%5E4,tau%3D-infinity..infinity)), the numerical value of $(f*g)(0)\approx\frac12$. Since $f*g$ continuous, it can thus not be $0$ almost everywhere.